# Complex differentiability of z*

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a complex function that can be written as $f = u(x,y) +j v(x,y)$, where $u(x,y)$  and $v(x,y)$  are  real  functions  of  two  real  inputs, while $z = x + j y$. If $f(z)$ is  complex-differentiable  at  a  given z,  then $u(x,y)$  and $v(x,y)$ must satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \Re{(f'(z))} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \Im{(f'(z))}
\end{equation}
The Cauchy-Riemann equations do not ensure analyticity of $f (z)$. Only if the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},\frac{\partial u}{\partial y},\frac{\partial v}{\partial x},\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ are continuous the Cauchy-Riemann equations are not only necessary but also sufficient to guarantee the analyticity of $f(z)$. When $f(z)$ is differentiable, we can write
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dz}f(z)= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+j \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} -j \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} 
\end{equation}
When considering $z^{*}=x-jy$, we can conclude that $z^{*}$ is not complex differentiable. As a matter of fact
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 1 \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = -1
\end{equation}
The infinitesimal increment used to differentiate $f(z)$ is a complex number, with a given module and argument. The  latter specifies the direction in the complex plane. The complex derivative is well-defined only if it is independent of the argument.

Now, we can differentiate $z^{*}$ with respect to $z$ using the chain rule as:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial z^{*}(x,y)}{\partial z}= \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}  \frac{\partial z^{*}}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial y}{\partial z}  \frac{\partial z^{*}}{\partial y}
\end{equation}
Where
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial z^{*}}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} (x-j y)= 1\\
\frac{\partial z^{*}}{\partial y} =\frac{\partial }{\partial y} (x-j y)=-j
\end{equation}
We need to differentiate $x$ and $y$ with respect to $z$. We can easily compute
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+j y)=1\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} =  \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x+j y)=j
\end{equation}
And then
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} =1\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = -j
\end{equation}
When substituting in the expression above we can conclude that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial z^{*}(x,y)}{\partial z}=0
\end{equation}
**Where I did the mistake?**
Thanks to the useful comment of Caffeine I added the following text. The Wirtinger derivatives are:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}-j\frac{\partial }{\partial x})(u(x,y)+j v(x,y))=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial u }{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y})+\frac{j}{2}(\frac{\partial v }{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y})\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z^{*}}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+j\frac{\partial }{\partial y})(u(x,y)+j v(x,y))=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial u }{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y})+\frac{j}{2}(\frac{\partial v }{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y})
\end{equation}
Thus, the Cauchy-Riemann equations are equivalent to the condition
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z^{*}}=0
\end{equation}
obtaibed by replacing the Cauchy-Riemann condition into the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z^{*}}$ expression, while $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ becomes:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial u }{\partial x}+j\frac{\partial v }{\partial x}
\end{equation}
On the other hand, by using the Wirtinger derivative, the expression $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$ reduces to:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u }{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0\\
\frac{\partial v }{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0
\end{equation}
Which is satisfied for $f(z)=z^{*}$. In addition when the Cauchy-Riemann condition is satisfied
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dz}f(z)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}
\end{equation}
Quite surprisingly
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial z^{*}(x,y)}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial z^{*}}=0
\end{equation}
which means that $z^{*}$ can be regarded as a constant with respect to $z$, as well as that $z$ can be regarded as a constant with respect to $z^{*}$.

Comment: The operator $\partial_z$ and the complex derivative are not the same thing, so you didn't prove that $\overline{z}$ is complex differentiable, you proved that $\partial_z \overline{z}=0$, which is correct (actually, a function is complex differentiable iff $\partial_\overline{z}f=0$). Google "Wirtinger derivatives" to find more info about the subject